# Google text-to-speech throw HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

We are developing a .Net 6 C# console app to transform a text files queue to audio files using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1  library

In dev computer all work fine, even in some workmates's computers work fine too. All of these are Window 10.

In Window 7 computers (ok, ok, still we have Window 7 pcs, we are sorry, :-)))). We install ed last version of .NET Desktop Runtime. When app call API service throw a exception:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.",
DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable
to establish HTTP/2 connection.

    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ThrowGetVersionException(HttpRequestMessage request, Int32 desiredVersion)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)"))
```

We have no idea what is happening and we don´t know where we start.
Please, Can anyone give us a solution or advice?

Thank a lot

Comment: I would like to know the same. As far as I can tell, .NET thinks that the server does not support HTTP/2, which happens in `HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync` and `HttpConnectionPool.HandleHttp11Downgrade`, called as a result from that. This happens during TLS negotiation, where `SslStream.NegotiatedApplicationProtocol == SslApplicationProtocol.Http2` seems to be false. Not sure why though, since I am pretty sure it worked in older versions (either of gRPC or .NET). Hopefully someone could pick up from there.

Comment: I think the problem is that HTTP/2 + TLS is not supported on windows 7 in Grpc.Net.Client, as explained here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1006